# What URLs are needed to use "Ok Google"?

Tags: firewall, ok-google

I own a fire tablet what I lock ALL internet traffic for using my router configuration. Works as expected.

But while I need no Internet at all on that device I want to use "Ok Google" which itself needs to have internet connection to analyze my commands.

So my idea would be to whitelist the URLs needed for "Ok Google" to work. But I cannot find any list of those URLs on the net.

As my Router does not log any outgoing connection (at least not that I can watch it) I cannot just look into my router.

Long words short: Does anyone have a list of URLs needed for "OK Google" so I can whitelist them?

To clearify: I need a specific URL. So no "Google.com", but "assistant.google.com" (or what ever the right url might be)

Comment: Not that, but an idea "the other way around": you could use a tool like [Network Connections](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antispycell.connmonitor) to monitor what the Google app wants to access, see e.g. [this screenshot](https://lh4.ggpht.com/AUKJLdMdNB6mHkWvwizY16FmjO4AP1ecUtDaiUpbLzpwf7wCOa0hB3-jwZtB00mlaFlYwWToBzeFy81ZcrhO_io).

Comment: Looks promising. But seems not to display hostnames, but only IP-Addresses

Comment: True – but AFAIK one can use IP addresses with firewall rules :) Guess you mention this because you want to filter more closely, in case e.g. Playstore would use the same IP but a different URL? Might be good to specify that in your question if that's the case (you know, not everybody goes through all the comments ;)